Error executing a file: bash: ./Test.elf: cannot execute: required file not found
Today I made a test program in C, which is a simple "Hello world.",
#include <stdio.h>

int _start(){
  printf("Hello, world!\n");
  return 0;
}

but I wanted to compile it in another way. I first compiled it with
gcc -c Test.c -o Test.o

and then linked it with
ld Test.o -lc -o Test.elf

. -lc to use the libc.so library for printf, but for some reason, when I try to run it with ./Test.elf, it tells me this error: bash: . /Test.elf: cannot execute: required file not found. If I don't try to run with gdb, it tells me that the error code is 127. As a matter of fact, I am trying all of this from Android, (to be able to program in aarch64), which I don't know if it influences this error. Could someone help me?
Edit:
I tried with this:
ld Main.o -o Main.elf -L. -lLibr --dynamic-linker=/system/lib64/ld-android.so
And now I get this error:
bash: ./Main.elf: Permission denied
I send
chmod 777 Test.elf
but I always get the same error.

The linking step is wrong.  You can't just use main as the entry point.  Also, the interpreter is likely set up wrong.

I have already solved it, the only thing I had to do was add this argument to the ld command -dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker64 (on Android) and also this other one -pie because after Android 5, this other argument is necessary.

gcc knows about main and start. Start is the real entry point, it sets up the C run-time, then calls main.
The simplest thing to do is not specify the entry point, and use gcc as your linker. gcc will link in the c runtime, and set the correct entry point.
gcc test.o -o Test


To find out more about what gcc dose to link the crt, see
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Initialization.html

Hello, I have changed the main to _start and linked it without the --entry, but the same thing keeps happening to me.

I have now added some clarification, fixed an error in the answer, and given a working solution.

I know that with gcc, It work good, but I want to link it with ld for undestanding how it works and for testing some thinks. Do you know how to link it withld without getting that error?

I have added a bit a about crt.
